# Angular 4 - Blocked loading mixed active content

Tags: angular, ssl, https

I'm using angular 4 as my frontend which is accessed over https (for location permissions) and it have ssl installed

The problem when calling the backend over http i get Blocked loading mixed active content error on browser because the backend doesn't have ssl installed.

Anyway to override this issue ?

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: @li-raz had to make all the request https, no other way, only images are allowed